# Override ~/.gradle/init.gradle repository location

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, jvm

Is there a way to change the location of the default repositories in a projects build.gradle? I'm using a company PC which has a `~/.gradle/init.gradle` file that globally specifies the default gradle repos like:

```
allProjects {
  buildscript {
    repositories {
       mavenLocal()
       maven { url "<company url>"}
    }
  } 
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "< company repo url>"}
  }
}
```

I can only access this while on the company network which means for any side project the build fails if I don't log on. Is there a way I can override this repo in the project to point to a different (public) repo? I've tried various things like changing the *project* `build.gradle` to have:

```
repositories {
  maven {
    url "https://maven.springframwork.org/release"
  }
}
```

But it still tries to point to the company repo and fails to resolve it.

Comment: You can't _override_ init.gradle, but you can add some other init scripts, providing some additional repositories (official docs have an exhaustive [list of ways](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html#sec:using_an_init_script) to do this), or add them directly in build.gradle, so it should work. What exact error do you get? Is it related to missing dependencies or missing Gradle plugins? Have you tried just simple `mavenCentral()`? Because "https://maven.springframwork.org/release" is not a resolvable URL, and "https://maven.springframEwork.org/release" returns 404.

Comment: I've tried adding `mavenCentral()` to the build.gradle, and it still attempts to resolve the dependencies to my companies repository.  Specifically I get something like:


```
> Could not resolve : <kotlin plugin>
> Could not get resource: '<company artifactory/repository link>'
> Connection to <company repo> timed out
```

Comment: Ok, so you have a problem with resolving the Gradle plugin. Repositories for plugins are defined separately from repositories for libraries (dependencies) - in the [`pluginManagement {repositories { } }`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_management)  section of `settings.gradle`/`init.gradle`. The problem here is that `init.gradle` overrides local settings of `settings.gradle`, so you need another init script with a higher priority to override it and add `gradlePluginPortal()` repository (it contains Kotlin plugin).

Comment: I don't think I can add an init script with higher priority that doesn't break all my work repos. It doesn't seem like I can force the override at the actual (non work) project level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to add some repositories for dependencies - you can do it right in the `build.gradle`.
If you want to override Gradle plugin repositories, defined in global init script, only for a specific project(s), you need to:

1. Create an init script, [which would be executed after](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html#sec:using_an_init_script) `init.gradle` in `USER_HOME/.gradle/` directory (for instance, `init.gradle.kts` in the `USER_HOME/.gradle/init.d/` directory)
2. Use some `if`-condition to specify what projects will be covered with this override (for instance, in some specific folder). Gradle scripts are not only a DSL, you can use all power of Turing-complete Groovy/Kotlin.

I'll use Kotlin here (probably, it's a valid Groovy code too):

```kotlin
settingsEvaluated {
    if (rootProject.projectDir.toString().startsWith("path/to/my/side/projects/folder")) {
        pluginManagement {
            repositories {
                gradlePluginPortal()
                mavenLocal()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bit of a shame you can't manually override within the project's `build.gradle` but your approach does allow me to set plugin repository for an entire directory which works well. Thanks for taking the time to help!